# ssl_error_rx_record_too_long showing up on firefox

Tags: ssl, virtualhost

I've got my regular wamp installation, and everything has been working fine with other vhosts, until I tried to make a vhost for DooPHP framework and I got an ssl_error_rx_record_too_long error on Firefox. It loads up fine in Chrome. I'm not using any SSL certs. My vhost configuration is just like all the rest of them:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin arturas@duomenucentras.lt
   DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/doophp/"
   ServerName doophp
   ServerAlias doo
   ErrorLog "logs/doo-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/doo-access.log" combined
   <Directory "C:/wamp/www/doophp/">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

Ok, now it stopped saying ssl_error_rx_record_too_long and just says "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at doo.". It loads up and works in Chrome, IE, Safari, Opera. Just not Firefox. What is up with that?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to enable SSL.
You need this in your virtualhost entry

```
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/yourhost.pem
```

If you have bought a cert you can use that or

```
    openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout yourhost.pem -out yourhost.pem
```

**Edit**:
are you sure your app does not redirect to ssl?

The message you got is the one you got when you speak https with a http server.

Comment: the thing is, i'm not using any certificate (it's just test of DooPHP framework) - and other virtual hosts work fine.

Comment: I re-read your question and made some updates